# What is the default limit on the number of transactions returned for a `Server.transactions` request?

Tags: javascript-sdk, horizon

Using the Stellar Javascript SDK, what is the maximum number of transactions that will be returned for a request to `server.transactions().forAccount(accountId).call()` before I have to worry about paging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum number of transactions on a single page is 200. Default is 10.